# Basic limit with an edge: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0.\overline9}f(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x\ne1$} \\
2, & \text{if $x$=1}
\end{cases}$

Then what is the result of this limit?

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0.\overline9}f(x)$$

Notice it's the limit of $x\to 0.\overline9$

I have always learned that $0.\overline9$ equals $1$ but it made me wonder in this specific case.

What is the right answer and more importantly, why?

Comment: in the formal definition of the limit, we never actually reach the limit, so I believe the answer is zero - x will never be 1.  In my opinion $.\overline9 = 1$

Comment: Would you have a problem with $$\lim_{x\to\left|\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)\right|} f(x)$$

Comment: This reminds me of a cartoon showing a bunch of excited math students wearing T-shirts declaring "We are number $0.\overline9$ !

Answer (score 1):

1. $0.\overline9=1$.
2. $\lim\limits_{x \to 0.\overline9}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}f(x)=0$

Answer (score 0):

$0,\bar 9 = 1$, and the distinction between both notations does not matter here.

By definition $\lim\limits_{x  \rightarrow a} f(x) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)$, if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)$ attains the same value for all sequences $x_n$, such that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = a$.

Take $x_n = 1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n = 1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n) = f(1) = 2$.

Take $x_n = 1 - \frac 1 n$, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n = 1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(1-\frac 1 n) = 0$.

So for your function $f$ we can not calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{x  \rightarrow 1} f(x)$.

Comment: Your definition of $\lim\limits_{x  \rightarrow a} f(x) $ is not correct. The correct definition: $\lim\limits_{x  \rightarrow a} f(x) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)$, if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)$ attains the same value for all sequences $x_n$, such that $x_n \ne a$ for all n and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = a$.